Hilt SingletonComponent vs ActivityComponent scope
I have an app with three activities.
Launch Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity -> C
Previous activity is finished while navigating to next activity.
I am injecting objects in Activity A and Activity B in the following way

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class MyProvider {

   // Provides object in Activity A
   @Provides
   fun provideTheObjectA(): SomeObjectA {
       return SomeObjectA()
   }
}


@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
class AvtivtyBProvider {

  // Provides object in Activity B
  @Provides
  fun provideTheObjectB(): SomeObjectB {
      return SomeObjectB()
  }
}

class ActivtyA: AppCompatActivity(){

  @Inject
  SomeObjectA
}

class ActivtyB: AppCompatActivity(){

  @Inject
  SomeObjectB
}

I want to understand the difference between SingletonComponent and ActivityComponent here.
So,

when activity A is destroyed, will the object A also be destroyed? (Its generated under SingletonComponent scope) (Note: I am not using the @Singleton annotation
) I believe it will be destroyed/garbage collected.
If I had provided the @Singleton annotation, I assume Object A will not be destroyed/garbage collected even though activity A is destroyed.

If so What is the point of @SingletonComponent if I have not used @Singleton annotation?

I assume that when Activity B is destroyed, object B will also be destroyed/garbage collected.

I have not used @ActivtyScoped while created instance of Object B. What difference does it make?

What does having just @Provides annotation without any scope mean ultimately



SingletonComponent and ActivityComponent are definitions of the scope.

Note: When scoping a binding within an @InstallIn module, the scope on
the binding must match the scope of the component. For example, a
binding within an @InstallIn(ActivityComponent.class) module can only
be scoped with @ActivityScoped.

In your case SomeObjectB can't be @Singleton, only @ActivityScoped.

Component lifetimes are generally bounded by the creation and
destruction of a corresponding instance of an Android class.




@Provides without any scope will create a new object anytime you inject it. @Provides is used only in a module @Module. That's the point of having no scope.




See 5.




Yes, because it is not scoped to the component (@Singleton/@ActivityScoped)




Yes.




Yes, it will. The point is that you can ask for ObjectA in ActivityB too(as well as everywhere in the app)




I understood the differences, However there is one thing that still is not clear.
Adding @Singleton makes the object singleton. This is clear. What value does adding @ViewmodelScoped and @ActivityScoped provide? I don't see any differences. Since these can only injected in viewmodels and activities and cleared when destroyed. What value does those 2 annotations add?

@abhishek-maharajpet Adding @Singleton does not make the object Singleton. It is telling the module it is installed in to keep it as a singleton. Those scoped annotations are functionally  @Singleton but are named differently because they are still limited to the lifecycle of the scope they are in.

@ViewmodelScoped provides the dependent classes that need this injection with same instance else separate instances. I just tested it out , same applies for  @ActivityScoped.
However I did not get your recent point about Singleton. Adding @Singleton to an object in @SingletonComponent makes it singleton across entire app right?

@abhishekmaharajpet Yes, @ Singleton in the SingletonComponent makes it singleton for the whole app essentially. It's the When scoping a binding within an @ InstallIn module, the scope on the binding must match the scope of the component.. You can use @ Singleton only in SingletonComponent, @ ViewModelScoped only in ViewModelComponent. etc.
